# Subscribing Solana Transfers

Tags: solana-program, web3.js, sol

Is it possible to subscribe program by passing SOL program ID to track SOL transfers? I'd like to track the SOL transfers by subscribing blocks any help appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to "subscribing" is to poll using the `getBlocksWithLimit` and `getBlock` JSONRPC methods (or your favorite SDK's wrappers).

`getBlocksWithLimit` is a light-weight call, that takes a `start_slot` and `count` and returns all `Slot`s which actually produced `Block`s in that range.  It can be polled periodically, starting from the slot height of last `Block` you've processed and with whatever `count` is a reasonable chunk of work for your application

`getBlock` can then be used to get the `Block` data for each slot returned by `getBlocksWithLimit.  Since this call can be *very* heavy, it is preferred to keep the call rate to a minimum, hence ensuring you will actually get data with the lighter call

Comment: The reason why I'd like to track SOL transfers is that I'm working in a crypto exchange market and we will list SOL. If a customer deposits SOL , I'd like to catch the address to validate the deposit. Is it doable with your recommendations? I wanted to subscribe to the blocks but subscribeBlocks is unstable, it disconnects after 2 mins.

Comment: What I proposed here is _exactly_ how nearly every exchange I'm aware of indexes blocks for Solana. It is very flexible and robust, unlike websocket subscriptions

Answer (score 0):

Yes sure, you can use Solana Web3 library for JS ,or if you use other programming language library for that language, and do something like this https://solanacookbook.com/references/local-development.html#subscribing-to-events . Also you can use direct JSON RPC API and handle WebSocket yourself and subscribe to account you want to track https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api#accountsubscribe